# "Everyday life" or "every-day life" or "every day life"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I can see around me that the term *everyday life* is the correct one used broadly.

But why shouldn't it be *every-day life*? That seems to fit with the grammatical pattern of similar constructions:

- *Everyday* is not a word in itself but should be *every* and *day*, as in:

  > It happens every day
- Just like *inbetween* is not a word but should rather be *in* and *between*, as in:

  > You are standing in between those two

When I use these sets of two words descriptively in front of a noun (I don't know the terminology for this, but I hope you can catch the meaning from the question), I would merge the two words with a dash:

> - Every-day life is hard.
> - The in-between people are gone.

This is apparently correct in the latter example but not in the former. **What is the difference? Why is *everyday life* not written as *every-day life*?**

Comment: Relevant: https://www.reuters.com/article/us-britain-hyphen-1/thousands-of-hyphens-perish-as-english-marches-on-idUSHAR15384620070921 Basically, over time, hyphens are dropped and word combinations become new words.

Comment: By now you might be starting to realize that every pattern in English has at least one exception.

Comment: *Everyday* is a word, and it means ordinary. If you want an adjective that means each day, then use *daily*. (1) *everyday life* → ordinary life (2) *daily life* → life that happens every day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of hyphenation with adjective phrases is correct, but *everyday* **is** a word.

> **everyday**  (adjective)
>
> : encountered or used routinely or typically : ordinary
>
> // *everyday* clothes

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/everyday

So then, why is *everyday* written as one word, while other phrasal adjectives are written with hyphens? Just because it's so old and so common. The use of *everyday* seems to go back to the 17th century ([*Etymology Online Dictionary*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/everyday)).

Note that people often incorrectly write "everyday" when they mean "every day."  For example (all taken from Stack Overflow posts): "I would like to know if Customer Ben received unique Item 1 everyday", "I need the system to run the following code everyday", "I want to run a Job Service everyday daily at 6:00 AM."

My favorite, which I read on an advertisement for a hostel in Brazil: "Everyday Monkeys" (I was looking forward to exotic monkeys, not your everyday monkeys).